# Using pandas and matplotlib.pyplot, how would I successfully graph a csv file with ~25k points?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

After reading the csv file and importing it into a DataFrame, there are two columns which I am trying to respectively graph (~25k points total). I have the following code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/ephemeralhappiness/Desktop/Path/Data Example.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Displacement Into Surface', 'Load On Sample'])
a = df.loc[0, 'Displacement Into Surface']
b = df.loc[0, 'Load On Sample']
df = df.drop([0])
x = df['Load On Sample']
y = df['Displacement Into Surface']
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Load On Sample')
plt.ylabel('Displacement Into Surface')
plt.gca().set_xticks([0, 500000000, 1000000000, 1500000000, 2000000000, 2500000000])
plt.gca().set_yticks([-1500, 0, 1500, 3000, 4500, 6000])
plt.show()
```

Here is an image of the graph upon running it (in PyCharm SciView btw):

[image: Displacement vs Load]

Here is a link to the example data file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RcHzEAS1tELgln9lIh5QuR5wzXinbN1y/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data has two header rows. Since the second header is just unit, you can skip it:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/quang/Downloads/Data Example.csv', skiprows=[1])

# plot the data:
df.plot(x='Load On Sample', y='Displacement Into Surface' )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes that makes sense...the reason I dropped the first row instead was so I could first save the units for later into variables.

Comment: When I plot x and y as points though, the graph becomes very distorted. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ephemeralhappiness your code shows `scatter`. You may want to replace `.plot(` with `.plot.scatter(`. Otherwise, the code just shows your data.

Comment: I see that makes sense. So I changed my code to incorporate pandas plotting library like you did. How do I actually show the graph though?

Comment: My SciView on PyCharm doesn't show anything when I run your plotting code. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think I figured it out...for whatever reason, it won't display in my SciView but it'll display when I turn off SciView and run it in the backend MacOSX.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the pandas plotting library.

```
df.plot()
```

Comment: I essentially get the same result using pandas plotting library versus matplotlib.pyplot.

Comment: Sorry Thought it would be worth a shot. I didn't have time to play with the example dataframe.

Comment: No worries. I'll look into the plotting library.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read csv
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# units
a = df.loc[0, 'Displacement Into Surface']
b = df.loc[0, 'Load On Sample']

# skip first row
df = df.loc[df.index > 0]

# reset index - start with 0
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

# change datatype to float
df = df.astype('float64')

# plotting a scatter-plot
plt.scatter(y=df['Displacement Into Surface'], x=df['Load On Sample'])
plt.show()
```

Output
[scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFcUN.png)

Your data were not set to float64. The mixed datatypes in the rows - string(units) and floats - made it difficult but possible.

I hope my code solved your problem.